# PostgreSQL mysticism with timestamp field

Tags: postgresql, gentoo

I have PostgreSQL database table with `timestamp with time zone`
field called `published_date`.

I use `psql -U postgres dbname` command for access my database.

When I try to update published_date field value by command:

```
UPDATE mytable SET published_date='PUBLISHED_DATE' WHERE id=3;
```

I get following results for corresponding PUBLISHED_DATEs:

```
SOURCE              -> RESULT

2013-01-16 20:00:00 -> 2013-01-16 20:00:00+00 (WELL)
2013-02-16 20:00:00 -> 2013-02-16 20:00:00+00 (WELL)
2013-03-16 20:00:00 -> 2013-03-16 20:00:00+00 (WELL)
2013-04-16 20:00:00 -> 2013-04-16 20:00:00+01 (STRANGE!)
2013-05-16 20:00:00 -> 2013-05-16 20:00:00+01 (STRANGE!)
2013-06-16 20:00:00 -> 2013-06-16 20:00:00+01 (STRANGE!)
2013-07-16 20:00:00 -> 2013-07-16 20:00:00+01 (STRANGE!)
2013-08-16 20:00:00 -> 2013-08-16 20:00:00+01 (STRANGE!)
2013-09-16 20:00:00 -> 2013-09-16 20:00:00+01 (STRANGE!)
2013-10-16 20:00:00 -> 2013-10-16 20:00:00+01 (STRANGE!)
2013-11-16 20:00:00 -> 2013-11-16 20:00:00+00 (WELL)
2013-12-16 20:00:00 -> 2013-12-16 20:00:00+00 (WELL)
```

There is UTC timezone in database:

```
=> SHOW timezone;
 TimeZone 
----------
 UTC
(1 row)
```

and system:

```
$ date
Tue Dec 17 00:14:12 GMT 2013
```

PostgreSQL version is 9.2.4

Same version of postgres compiled with same flags installed on another machine working pretty! Very strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the normal behaviour, PostgreSQL tries to accomodate the user when outputting a timestamp with timezone (which internally is indeed stored as UTC).  I assume you're in the UK, what you see is it changing between summer and winter time.  From the manual, emphasis added:

> For timestamp with time zone, the internally stored value is always in
>   UTC (Universal Coordinated Time, traditionally known as Greenwich Mean
>   Time, GMT). An input value that has an explicit time zone specified is
>   converted to UTC using the appropriate offset for that time zone. If
>   no time zone is stated in the input string, then it is assumed to be
>   in the time zone indicated by the system's timezone parameter, and is
>   converted to UTC using the offset for the timezone zone.
>
> When a timestamp with time zone value is output, ***it is always
>   converted from UTC to the current timezone zone, and displayed as
>   local time in that zone.*** To see the time in another time zone, either
>   change timezone or use the AT TIME ZONE construct (see Section 9.9.3).